# redux-react simple hello world

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux - why doesn't `mapStateToProps` get called and the component update to show 'hello world'?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyXyvW?editors=0011

```
const helloReducer = (state= {message:'none'}, action) => {    
 switch (action.type) {
    case 'HELLO':
      return Object.assign(state,{message:"hello world"});
    default:
      return state;
  }  
};
const myApp = Redux.combineReducers({
  helloReducer
});    
const App = ({onClick,message}) => (
  <div>
    <a href="#" onClick={onClick}>click</a><b>{message}</b>
  </div>
);
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {message: state.message}
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch({type: 'HELLO'})
    }
  }
}   
const ConnectedApp = ReactRedux.connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
let Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
let store = Redux.createStore(myApp)
let e = React.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning directly to "state" in your reducer, which is mutating it directly.  You need to return `Object.assign({}, state, {message:"hello world"});` instead.

Also note that React-Redux does a lot of work to make sure that a component's `mapStateToProps` function only runs when it absolutely has to.

Comment: Now that's tricky. I missed it during attempting to debug the question. This is a potentially good reason to use the es6 spread operator `return { ...state, { message: "hello" };` which in my opinion is more obvious and readable here.

Comment: Yeah, mutating state is the #1 answer to "why is my component not updating?", which is why it's going to go into the Redux FAQ page I'm working on right now.

Answer (score 0):

replace line : `return Object.assign(state,{message:"hello world"});`

with this: `return  {...state, message:"hello world"};`

It is ES6 spread operator.